# How to structure an Analytics System

Tags: cloud, analytics, webhooks

I want to study which devices send requests to a server (PHP - Wordpress).
Hence store a new record (containing the User Agent string) every time the server receive a request.
I need also to be able to read records via Google Sheets.

I'm new to this and before start coding i'm doing research to define which "infrastructure" is better, and requires me less effort.
I'm asking here because maybe someone have been done this in the past and could tell his insights.

> Note:
> I don't have access to the browser's javascript .
> Every request the server receives is redirected to an external website.
> I can use only the server to orchestrate all things.

Here are some path i thought of:

1. **Basic**

Store records in a Wordpress custom table.

Create a REST API inside Wordpress that read data from that table.

When i want to analyze data i fetch the record from REST API in Google Sheets via Google App Scripts.

2. **Basic with Firebase**.

Store records in a Firebase table.

When i want to analyze data i fetch the record from Firebase REST API in Google Sheets via Google App Scripts.

Here i find difficult to understand how to setup Authentication, Client ID , API Keys, etc in Google Console.(Never used before)

3. **Google Sheets as DB**.

When server receive a request , server send an other request to Google Sheets directly, using some sort of Google Sheets Client SDK in PHP.

Here i find difficult to understand how to setup Authentication, Client ID , API Key, etc in Google Console.(Never used before)

4. **Webhook way**.

When server receive a request , server send an other request to a Cloud Function hosted in Netlify or Similar.

The Cloud Function send record to Google Sheets , using some sort of Google Sheets Client SDK in Node.js.

Here i find difficult to understand how to setup Authentication, Client ID , API Key, etc in Google Console.(Never used before)

Which path would you choose?
Would you do something different ?

Any good resource to understand Authentication in Google Ecosystem?

Security side, now i store only User Agent string, but in future i could store more sensitive, so it's good idea to use this project to learn something reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it's extremely unlikely that you will be satisfied with just the device information in any analysis, but in this answer, I will presume that you know your situation better than I.

Your options:

1. Sounds fine. Primitive, but sure.
2. Firebase/GA is large. You probably don't wanna complicate things with them. They demand very certain data structure in order to be able to give fullest insights. But later, when you want to get the data back, it's not that straightforward since those APIs are meant for pretty serious ETL process with exact understanding of all their internal definitions. It will be annoying if your aim is just to get a few metrics and a few dimensions and never anything more.
3. I never used Sheets APIs when the sheet is not opened. I always use its internal pseudo JS to move the data around. Well, it's up to you.
4. That's just a variation of 3.

Okay, now how I would do it.

You have (or supposed to have) access logs on the backend. If what you've described is all you need, I would suggest feeding the access logs as they are to G sheets and be done with it. That would be the sturdiest and most reliable implementation and if done correctly, it won't even depend on your backend language, but just on the web-server logging.

Well, if your setup typically bypasses the web-server (which is annoying really), then the framework you use for managing endpoints would likely have semblance of logging in it. I would use that then.

If not, I would try doing my tracking on the front-end, too, but you mentioned that that's not an option, so I'm not gonna entertain the thought any further.

Finally if those options aren't really options then you should think if you want to bother aggregating the data on the fly, in your script or not. And you're unlikely to want that because that would be extremely annoying.

To that point, unaggregated data will take a lot of space. G Sheets won't be able to handle that amount of raw data. For the same reason, using your local DB may be a bad idea too.

So it may be better for you to use GA API to stream the data through their measurement protocol (there are multiple libraries available for it). GA has an ability to feed its data to BQ, and from BQ it's much easier to get it to wherever. Well, I believe there already are multiple scripts and plugins for G sheets to get aggregated data from GA and make a semblance of semi-live dashboards in it.

Comment: Thanks for your time and response, I really appreciate it.

@BNazaruk
I tried method 4, configuring the data paths.
It works, but I think it is unnecessarily complex.
Since then I should build scripts for data reporting and periodic data cleaning.

Comment: Following your advice I'm reading how GA works (I'm newbie here too) and I'll give an attempt with Measurement Protocol.


My first goal is to understand from which other platform/page people come to my site (I was thinking about the HTTP_REFERRAL of PHP variable and links with custom query strings).

My second goal is to understand what percentage of the site is used by smartphones and desktops for a more conscious frontend development.


With GA can I skip the building of these reports? They are auto generated?

Comment: Yes, these reports are pretty trivial in GA. You should probably start doing GA then. Just go with GA UA, don't do GA4. GA4 is still a really raw product, effectively beta.